# How to pass variable to require module in require js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

I have changed my js and splitted into multiple files. Now file is triggered when module is called. But there is 1 issue I am unable to send variable data to that file. Below is the example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var academic_master = {};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        async: false,
        data: 'pathname=' + pathname + '&action=5',
        success: function (response) {
            if (page_type === '0' && currentUrl === 'academic/studentcourseallocation')
            {
                require(['studentcourseallocation'], function(academic_master){});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here "studentcourseallocation" is a file which is called in require.config.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: ASSETSURL,
    waitSeconds: 30,
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min',
        'studentcourseallocation': 'js/PATH/studentcourseallocation',

    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'studentcourseallocation': ['jquery'],
    }
});
```

Now I am unable to get "academic_master" variable in "studentcourseallocation.js"

Please suggest!!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Now I have made

```
var academic_master = {};
```

global, added before require.config.js and its working fine